# Create local copy of Ubuntu remote repository

Tags: repository, localrepository

Good day.
I'm trying to create local copy of official Ubuntu repository(12.10 or 13.10 does not matter). 
As far as i know i could recursively download all packages from the mirror (http://mirror.yandex.ru/) but there is any othe way to do the job?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to copy everything is to use rsync :

```
 rsync -a --bwlimit=128 rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu /media/mirror/ubuntu
```

Here's more info on the matter : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rsyncmirror

Rsync is a great tool.

EDIT to add it as your default repository to your hosts :

Publish the mirror on the Apache server
This is the easy part. Assuming that you have Apache configured to follow symbolic links, all you need to do is add a symbolic link to your mirror!

```
 cd /var/www/
 ln /media/mirror/ubuntu -s
```

You can test to see if this was successful by using a web browser to visit the site. Goto ubuntumirror.mydomain/ubuntu

You should see some directories named "dists", "indices", "pool", "project", and a file named "ls-lR.gz".

Update Your Clients
Now that you have your very own Ubuntu Mirror, you need to point all of your workstations and servers to this mirror for their updates. This mirror will be good for main, universe, multi-verse, and restricted.

Replace the server name for the Ubuntu Archives with your local mirror. The existing server will likely be something like us.ubuntu.com

If your server is called ubuntumirror.mydomain then your /etc/apt/sources.list file should look something like this

```
 deb http://ubuntumirror.mydomain/ubuntu/ feisty main restricted
 deb-src http://ubuntumirror.mydomain/ubuntu/ feisty main restricted

 deb http://ubuntumirror.mydomain/ubuntu/ feisty-updates main restricted
 deb-src http://ubuntumirror.mydomain/ubuntu/ feisty-updates main restricted
```

You can test your mirror by running

```
 # apt-get update
```

You should see some output referencing your server, similar to this:

```
 Get:1 http://ubuntumirror.mydomain feisty Release.gpg [191B]
 Ign http://ubuntumirror.mydomain feisty/main Translation-en_US
 Ign http://ubuntumirror.mydomain feisty/restricted Translation-en_US
 Get:2 http://ubuntumirror.mydomain feisty-updates Release.gpg [191B]
 Ign http://ubuntumirror.mydomain feisty-updates/main Translation-en_US
 Ign http://ubuntumirror.mydomain feisty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
```

Comment: but how to setup my own server as repository?

Comment: At the end of the link.

Comment: Doesn't your method back up every version of Ubuntu, including distant past ones? How do use rsync to backup selected areas of the repositories, such as only Trusty (and its updates), and/or only AMD64 archictecture? For example, all Lubuntu amd64 Trusty packages and updates.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is very old so if you are not already familiar with it allow me to introduce you to Debmirror. It is a utility for making a partial local mirror for Debian and Ubuntu based systems. As the man page of debmirror says: "It can mirror any combination of architectures, distributions, and sections. ...with ftp, http or rsync and package pool support." Please note that debmirror only copies a mirror. To serve that copy to different clients wanting to install various packages you need something like an FTP server, web server, etc.

The steps to build a mirror with debmirror are described excellently at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror

I will be summarizing the steps below for your ease of reference:

1. Suppose you have an ubuntu server with sufficient storage space (~200GB to be safe), sudo access and fast internet connection (~10 MB/s for overnight download). First install debmirror and some other packages on it:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install debmirror gnupg xz-utils
```

2. We will make our mirror in a subdirectory of the `/opt/` directory:

```
$ sudo mkdir /opt/UbuntuMirror
```

3. Make the file `mirrorbuild.sh` in `/opt/UbuntuMirror/` directory and copy the following in that script. Once the copying is done, save it and make the script executable:

```
#### Start of script to automate building of Ubuntu mirror #####

#!/bin/bash
export GNUPGHOME=/opt/UbuntuMirror/mirrorkeyring
arch=amd64
section=main,restricted,universe,multiverse
release=focal,focal-security,focal-updates
server=archive.ubuntu.com
inPath=/ubuntu
proto=http
outPath=/opt/UbuntuMirror/ubuntu-mirror

debmirror       -a $arch \
                --no-source \
                -s $section \
                -h $server \
                -d $release \
                -r $inPath \
                --progress \
                --method=$proto \
                $outPath

#### End of script to automate building of Ubuntu mirror ####
```

The above script will download packages using http in the `/opt/UbuntuMirror/ubuntu-mirror/` directory. The packages will be from all sections (i.e. main, restricted, universe and multiverse) but will only be for amd64 architectures. No source packages will be downloaded. Keys will also be handled. Modify the above script according your needs.

4. We need some keys. For newer versions of Ubuntu do:

```
$ sudo mkdir /opt/UbuntuMirror/mirrorkeyring
$ gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /opt/UbuntuMirror/mirrorkeyring/trustedkeys.gpg --import /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
```

5. Now change the permissions and ownership on the mirror.

```
$ sudo chown -R root:root /opt/UbuntuMirror/mirrorkeyring
$ sudo chmod -R 571 /opt/UbuntuMirror/mirrorkeyring
```

6. Execute the script:

```
/opt/UbuntuMirror/mirrorbuild.sh
```

This step will take a long time to complete since it downloads a lot of data.

7. Once the download completes, your mirror is ready. You can also transfer the entire `/opt/UbuntuMirror/` directory to another server on a different network (not having internet access) if a mirror is required on that network.

Now I will show you how to serve the mirror with nginx to clients wanting to install various packages. You can skip this part if you want some other method to serve the mirror.

1. Suppose you copy the mirror to another server (or keep on the same server) which has Nginx installed. Suppose the mirror is located at the path `/usr/share/nginx/html/UbuntuMirror/`.
2. Create `/etc/nginx/conf.d/repo.conf` and copy the following in it. Be sure to enter your server's IP before saving and closing.

```
server {
        listen   80;
        autoindex on;
        server_name  <insert your server's IP here>;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/UbuntuMirror;
        index index.html; 
        location / {
                autoindex on;
        }
}
```

You can modify the above according to your needs.

3. Restart Nginx

```
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

To use the above mirror from the above server:

1. first take the backup of client's original `sources.list` file

```
$ sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.orig
```

2. Now create a new `/etc/apt/sources.list/` with the following contents:

```
deb http://<insert your server's IP here>/ubuntu-mirror focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://<insert your server's IP here>/ubuntu-mirror focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://<insert your server's IP here>/ubuntu-mirror focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

3. Now you can use the mirror from the server:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install <some_package>
```